# Proving $(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+3b}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+3a}})\leqq 2$

Tags: inequality

For $a,b>0.$ Prove$:$ $$(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+3b}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+3a}})\leqq 2$$
My proof$:$

Let $a=\frac{x^2}{z}, b=\frac{y^2}{z}$ then $x,y,z>0.$ We need to prove$:$
$$\Big(\frac{x}{\sqrt{z}} +\frac{y}{\sqrt{z}}\Big) \cdot \Big( \frac{\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{x^2+3y^2}} +\frac{\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{3x^2+y^2}}\Big) \leqq 2$$
Or $$\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+3y^2}} +\frac{1}{\sqrt{3x^2 +y^2}}  \leqq \frac{2}{x+y}$$
By C-S we have$:$ $$\text{LHS}^2 \leqq  ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+3y^2}} +\frac{1}{\sqrt{3x^2 +y^2}})^2 \leqq 2 (\frac{1}{x^2+3y^2}+\frac{1}{3x^2+y^2}) \leqq \frac{4}{(x+y)^2} \leqq \text{RHS}^2$$
The last inequality is very easy! But is there another proof$?$

Comment: Why does your proof need to introduce $z$? I think it is exactly the same as putting $a = x^2$ and $b = y^2$.

Comment: The quantities are homogeneous, so you can write everything in terms of $t=b/a$. The claim reads then 
$$(1+\sqrt t)(\frac1{\sqrt{1+3t}}+\frac1{\sqrt{3+t}})\le2.$$
This should be easier to attack. For example as a single variable calculus problem.

Comment: Various solutions on AoPS: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(%5Csqrt%7Ba%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7Bb%7D)(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Ba%2B3b%7D%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bb%2B3a%7D%7D)%5Cleqq%202%24&p=1.

Answer (score 1):

For example.

Let $a+b=2u\sqrt{ab}.$

thus, by AM-GM $u\geq1$ and we need to prove that
$$\sqrt{a+b+2\sqrt{ab}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{4a+4b+2\sqrt{3a^2+3b^2+10ab}}}{\sqrt{3a^2+3b^2+10ab}}\leq2$$ or
$$\sqrt{2u+2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{8u+2\sqrt{12u^2+4}}}{\sqrt{12u^2+4}}\leq2$$ 
or $$6u^2+2\geq(u+1)(2u+\sqrt{3u^2+1})$$ or
$$4u^2-2u+2\geq(u+1)\sqrt{3u^2+1}$$ or
$$13u^4-22u^3+16u^2-10u+3\geq0$$ or
$$13u^4-13u^3-9u^3+9u^2+7u^2-7u-3u+3\geq0$$ or
$$(u-1)(13u^3-9u^2+7u-3)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

By this way we can get a best estimation here:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive numbers and $2-\sqrt3\leq k\leq 2+\sqrt3.$ Prove that:
>    $$(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{ka+b}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+kb}}\right)\leq\frac{4}{\sqrt{k+1}}.$$

Comment: I want to write the last inequaility as  $$(\sqrt{ a + ka} + \sqrt{b + kb})\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ a + kb}} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{b + ka}}\right) \le 4$$.

Comment: @dust05 It's not inequality. It;s expression, which by C-S is $\geq4$.

Comment: please read my comment once more.

Comment: @dust05 It's $\sqrt{b+ka}$ or $\sqrt{b+kb}$?

Comment: I just multiplied $\sqrt{k+1}$ on each side and did $\sqrt{a(k+1)} = \sqrt{a + ka}$. It is just nothing, but looks better because there is some symmetry in LHS and RHS is a simple constant, in my opinion.

Comment: @dust05 If so, it's the same, of course. For me, my versa is better.